# OpenCV: get the L a b values of a pixel

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I convert a picture's colors to [LAB](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_Lab) as follows:

```
import cv2
imbgr=cv2.imread('rgbpic?jpg')
imlab=cv2.cvtColor(imbgr,cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
cv2.imwrite('lab.jpg',imlab)
```

Now, I wonder how can I get the `L`, `a` and `b`  values of a given pixel `p(x,y)` of `imlab` ?

Comment: Images are stored as arrays. Access individual values as you would the values of an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`imbgr` and `imlab` are standard numpy arrays. To access the pixel `p(x,y)`, use `imlab[y][x]`; the result is an array containing the 3 channel values.

Comment: how do I get the values ​​of the pixels of a Lab image and plot a 3d graph?

Answer (score 2):

I believe line three should be -

```
imlab=cv2.cvtColor(imbgr,cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
```

You can then just look up the indices of a pixel - eg

```
imlab[x,y]
```

will return the L,a,b values

Comment: Yes, you are right, I had a typo. I updated my question. Thank you very much.

Comment: how do I get the values ​​of the pixels of a Lab image and plot a 3d graph?