# OpenCV how to detect a specific color in a frame (inRange function)

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, opencv3.1

I am able to use the code below to find anything blue within a frame:

[How To Detect Red Color In OpenCV Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38877102/how-to-detect-red-color-in-opencv-python)

However I want to modify the code to look for a very specific color within a video that I have.  I read in a frame from the video file, and convert the frame to HSV, and then print the HSV values at a particular element (that contains the color I want to detect):

```
print("hsv[x][y]: {}".format(hsv[x][y]))
```

"hsv" is what I get after I convert the frame from BGR to HSV using cvtColor().
The print command above gives me:
hsv[x][y]: [108  27 207]

I then define my lower and upper HSV values, and pass that to the inRange() function:

```
lowerHSV = np.array([107,26,206])

upperHSV = np.array([109,28,208])

maskHSV = cv2.inRange(hsv, lowerHSV, upperHSV)
```

I display maskHSV, but it doesn't seem to identify the item that contains that color.  I try to expand the lowerHSV and upperHSV bounds, but that doesn't seem to work either.
I try something something similar using BGR but that doesn't appear to work.

The thing I'm trying to identify can best be described as a lemon-lime sports drink bottle...

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

=====================================================

## The complete python code I am running is shown below, along with some relevant images...

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 
import time

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture("conveyorBeltShort.wmv") 

xloc = 460

yloc = 60

dCounter = 0

while(1):

    dCounter += 1

    grabbed, frame = video_capture.read()

    if grabbed == False:
        break

    time.sleep(2)

    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    lowerBGR = np.array([200,190,180])
    upperBGR = np.array([210,200,190])

    # HSV [108 27 209] observation
    lowerHSV = np.array([105,24,206])
    upperHSV = np.array([111,30,212])

    maskBGR = cv2.inRange(frame, lowerBGR, upperBGR)
    maskHSV = cv2.inRange(hsv, lowerHSV, upperHSV)

    cv2.putText(hsv, "HSV:" + str(hsv[xloc][yloc]),(100,280), 
        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 3,(0,0,0),8,cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.putText(frame, "BGR:" + str(frame[xloc][yloc]),(100,480), 
        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 3,(0,0,0),8,cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (0, 0), (xloc-1, yloc-1), (255, 0, 0), 2)
    cv2.rectangle(hsv, (0, 0), (xloc-1, yloc-1), (255, 0, 0), 2)

    cv2.imwrite("maskHSV-%d.jpg" % dCounter, maskHSV)
    cv2.imwrite("maskBGR-%d.jpg" % dCounter, maskBGR)
    cv2.imwrite("hsv-%d.jpg" % dCounter, hsv) 
    cv2.imwrite("frame-%d.jpg" % dCounter, frame)

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv2.imshow('hsv',hsv)
    cv2.imshow('maskHSV',maskHSV)    
    cv2.imshow('maskBGR',maskBGR)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
video_capture.release()
```

=====================================================

first image is "frame-6.jpg"

second image is "hsv-6.jpg"

third image is "maskHSV-6.jpg"

fourth image is "maskBGR-6.jpg"

## maskHSV-6.jpg and maskBGR-6.jpg do not appear to show the lemon-lime bottle on the conveyor belt.  I believe I have the lower and upper HSV/BGR limits set correctly...

[image: frame-6.jpg]

[image: hsv-6.jpg]

[image: maskHSV-6.jpg]

[image: maskBGR-6.jpg]

Comment: can you provide some sample image?

Comment: Well structured question, good problem space definition. I would suggest adding some of your input and output images though as it will help us understand what you are getting and maybe solve the specific problem

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I modified the original post to include the entire python code I am running, along with images I am getting...  If you need more information, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I know only C++ for OpenCV, but according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717271/opencv-get-the-l-a-b-values-of-a-pixel) you should use img[y][x] or img[x,y] to access pixel value.

Your rgb value are not correct.It should be something like `[96,160,165]`.